# MySQL - Add columns on multiple JOIN matches

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm struggling a bit with a query, or at least in finding a way for it to work proficiently.
To summarize the problem, say I have two tables like theese:

TABLE 1:

| id_product | id_category |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 |
| A2 | 2 |
| A3 | 3 |

TABLE 2:

| id_category | id_lang | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Category 1 IT description |
| 1 | 2 | Category 1 EN description |
| 1 | 3 | Category 1 DE description |
| 2 | 1 | Category 2 IT description |
| 2 | 2 | Category 2 EN description |
| 2 | 3 | Category 2 DE description |

In which if I consider id_category for a JOIN I have multiple matches of course, for each language available.
The result I would like to have is something like:

| id_product | id_category | IT_desc | EN_desc | DE_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | Category 1 IT description | Category 1 EN description | Category 1 DE description |
| A2 | 2 | Category 2 IT description | Category 2 EN description | Category 2 DE description |

So having all matches in multiple columns, in order to see different language descriptions in a single entry.
The only thing I was able to do is to have multiple joins, each time for a different language, so something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_IT
ON t2_IT.id_lang = 1 AND t1.id_category = t2_IT.id_category
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_EN
ON t2_EN.id_lang = 2 AND t1.id_category = t2_EN.id_category
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2_DE
ON t2_DE.id_lang = 3 AND t1.id_category = t2_DE.id_category
```

This method actually works, but I was wondering if there's a better alternative out there, which doesn't involve multiplying joins each time, which can be slow when it comes to greater amount of datas.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Group on Joined table

> ```
> SELECT t1.`id_product`, t1.`id_category`,
> MAX(IF( `id_lang` = 1 ,  `description`, NULL)) IT_desc,
> MAX(IF( `id_lang` = 2 ,  `description`, NULL)) EN_desc,
> MAX(IF( `id_lang` = 3 ,  `description`, NULL)) DE_desc
> FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1. `id_category` = t2.`id_category`
> GROUP BY t1.`id_product`, t1.`id_category`
> ```
>
> ```
> id_product | id_category | IT_desc                   | EN_desc                   | DE_desc                  
> :--------- | ----------: | :------------------------ | :------------------------ | :------------------------
> A1         |           1 | Category 1 IT description | Category 1 EN description | Category 1 DE description
> A2         |           2 | Category 2 IT description | Category 2 EN description | Category 2 DE description
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af7137821fe743c05952b235be363b97)*

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!
I'm just missing a point: why is the grouping based on two fields?
I mean, shouldn't be id_product enough for grouping in this case...?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't log before. Thank you very much for the tip, it will be handy 'cause I usually don't have the need of huge queries (e.g. this in particular is a small part of a bigger one), only simple stuff :)